# Error 0x800700DF: The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved

Tags: open-with-explorer, limitations

I am using sp 2010. I have 2 differant web applications. I try to copy a pdf document from webapplication1 to webapplication2. I do this by opening the file explorer from these 2 webapplications. It is working with all small documents, but I have 1 big pdf document from 56 mb. It gives me this error:

> Error 0x800700DF: The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot
>   be saved

But when I copy this large pdf document to my local machine (desktop). And then copy this local pdf document to webapplication2 by the fileexplorer it is working fine. No errors. Also when I upload this document from the GUI in the document library in webapplication2 it is working fine without errors. So it looks like there is another limit in the fileexplorer which is not equal to the GUI. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 24):

By default, Windows has a ~47MB limit for this type of WebDav transfer.  Apparently it's a policy put in place as a security measure to ensure a misbehaving WebDav endpoint doesn't DOS/flood the client machine.

To change this setting on the client you need to edit the registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> Services -> WebClient -> Parameters` called `FileSizeLimitInBytes`.  You can set this to any legal 32-bit value you wish.  You may want to click on the `Decimal` type to make it easier to enter a value.  The max value you can use in this key (`4294967295`) will allow you to transfer about a ~4GB file.

Once you have saved this key, you'll need to restart the `WebClient` windows service (or reboot your machine if you wish).

Source: http://kx.cloudingenium.com/microsoft/servers/sharepoint/sharepoint-error-0x800700df-file-size-exceeds-limit-allowed-saved/

Comment: Why 32 bit? Is it because of machine or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There is a limit in Win 7. It is now 50 mb and can be increased in the registry.